# Why aren't all insulators transparent, since they have a large band gap?

Tags: optics, material-science, conductors, insulators

According to Floris' answer in this [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230346/why-is-diamond-transparent-while-graphite-is-not), diamonds are transparent as they have large band gaps while graphite is black as it is a conductor.

As electrical insulators generally have a large band gap, why aren't all insulators transparent?

Comment: If pure without inclusions, defects, scattering centers, and whatnot, they generally will be transparent. For example, sapphire (crystalline aluminum oxide) is wonderfully transparent, while alumina-based ceramics often are not (due to grain sizes and impurities).

Comment: @JonCuster That sounds like a fairly complete answer.

Comment: @joncuster Sorry for the basic question but what about polymer such as plastic, rubber, wood, or ceramics ?